# How to add a digital signature to any given file using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, digital-signature

How to add a digital signature to any given file using python and verify  the same .  That is input a file and output a digitally signed file and giving a digitally signed file with a key verify the digital signature.  How to do this using python?

Comment: did you get solution? @PadmalochanPanda

Comment: Did you get any solution? @ChidanandaNayak

Answer (score 0):

GroupDocs.Signature Cloud SDK for Python can [digital sign](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/sign-document-with-digital-signature/) all common file formats and [verify](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/verify-digital-signatures/) the same from cloud storage. It is paid product but also provides 150 free API calls against a free trial. Currently, it supports the following providers along with default internal GroupDocs Cloud storage:

- Amazon S3 DropBox
- Google Drive Storage
- Google Cloud Storage Windows
- Azure Storage
- FTP Storage

P.S: I am a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.

Answer (score -1):

There are many packages presents.

pdfrw: Read and write PDF files; watermarking, copying images from one PDF to another. Includes sample code.

slate : Simplifies extracting text from PDF files. Wrapper around PDFMiner.

PDFQuery : PDF scraping with Jquery or XPath syntax. Requires PDFMiner, pyquery and lxml libraries.

PDFMiner : Extracting text, images, object coordinates, metadata from PDF files. Pure Python.

PyPDF2 : Split, merge, crop, etc. of PDF files.

Comment: Please get the question again ... its for adding digital signature to any file ..  not only PDF...